# php how to redirect user to index.html when sucessfully logging in

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, authentication, get

hi  i am having problems  with a login script for my website i need the script to  redrect the user to  index.html if the  login details are  correct. if you could help me at all it would be greatly appreciated.. thank you...

here is my script for checking the details ==>

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>

$ousername = '';
    //We check if the form has been sent
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
            $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
        }
        else
        {
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        }
        //We get the password of the user
        $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
        $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
        //We compare the submited password and the real one, and we check if the user exists
        if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            //If the password is good, we dont show the form
            $form = false;
            //We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
?>

<?php
        }
        else
        {
            //Otherwise, we say the password is incorrect.
            $form = true;
            $message = 'The username or password is incorrect.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
    }
    if($form)
    {
        //We display a message if necessary
    if(isset($message))
    {
        echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
    }
    //We display the form
?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.. thank you.

Comment: Try this: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* extensions anymore. Please look into `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: **[DANGER! You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**
 **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: i beginning to the ink the S.O mysql comment warnings are more a problem than the use of mysql.

Comment: Just as an FYI, storing a user's password in plain text is ***extremely discouraged*** as it poses a massive security risk (in addition to the above mentioned `mysql_*` extension security risks).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As **@Dagon** corrected me..

To redirect user back to index.html, you can use the following:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/index.html');
exit;
```

after successful login.

Comment: full URI for location.

Comment: I've using it like this and don't have problems so far. Can you explain a little why?

Comment: Nice thing about the answer given is that it will work on localhost during testing.

Comment: i can: **HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but *some* clients accept relative URIs.**

Comment: To extend on what @Dagon said, it's part of the official [HTTP/1.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) as defined in the link. Most browsers will still execute the above statement as most browsers attempt to correct some errors and make some assumptions. However, officially without the full _absolute url_, it technically goes against the specification.

Comment: Thank's is good to know! I guess I from this `some` clients since I don't have need to use full URI.

Comment: one day some browser will actully follow the spec, and half the php sits on the planet will fall over :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `header()` function after setting the user information in `$_SESSION`.

```
// If the password is good, we don't show the form
$form = false;
// We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
header('Location: http://example.com/index.html');
```

Comment: [See the above discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098621/php-how-to-redirect-user-to-index-html-when-sucessfully-logging-in#comment-44573199). When using the HTTP Location header, you should use the full ***absolute url*** in order to align your code properly with the defined specification.

Answer (score 0):

So your source code is not preferly the best to this way of login, but even in this way you should make a redirection after login.

It you can do with JavaScript, exactly i recomend you tu use jQuery API, which will help you to improve many things on your site.

So in your situation i recomend you this way of solution:

```
 if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            //If the password is good, we dont show the form
            $form = false;

            echo "<script>$('#idofelement2reload').load('php.php?login=1');</script>";

            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];

        }
```

So if you noticed, this line

```
echo "<script>$('#idofelement2reload').load('php.php?login=1');</script>";
```

writes a line into html document which call a function to load through jQuery a file with parameter that the user is logged in.

Don`t forget to include jQueries source code in head

Answer (score 0):

```
if($dn['password']==$password and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            //If the password is good, we dont show the form
            $form = false;
//We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
       header('Location:http://sitename.com/index.php');
?>
```